# Uso dell'espressione "vall’a sapere"

Tags: word-usage, colloquial

Nel racconto *Il pensatore* dei *Racconti romani*, di Alberto Moravia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Insomma, vuota o congelata che fosse la mia testa, ero proprio un cameriere perfetto, tanto che una volta sentii una ragazza, al ristorante, dire al suo compagno, indicandomi: “Ma guarda quel cameriere lì che faccia di cameriere che ci ha... quello per esempio non potrebbe essere che cameriere... è nato cameriere, e morirà cameriere...” Come poi sia la faccia da cameriere, **vall'a sapere**.

L'espressione "vall'a sapere" ha attirato la mia attenzione: penso di non averla trovata mai prima. È qualcosa di molto colloquiale? Corrisponde a "vallo a sapere"? Dove si usa? Cioè, si può sentire in tutta Italia o è regionale (magari di Roma)? Le espressioni "vai a sapere" o "va' a sapere" sono usate più spesso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come hai giustamente dedotto, `vall'a sapere` è una contrazione di `vallo a sapere`. In italiano io l'ho ascoltato da gente di tutte le regioni, in questa forma, o nelle varianti che proponi. Non saprei dire quale forma sia più comune, comunque.

Mi sembra proprio l'equivalente dello spagnolo `¡ve a saberlo!` o `¡vete a saberlo!`.

Comment: Grazie! In spagnolo, "vete a saber" o "vete tú a saber" sono anche molto comuni.